# Binary Image Size after import

Tags: image-processing, import, binary

I have a lot of binary images I would like to import into mathematica.

Each of them is 132kB (1024x1024) big. Like the following:[image: binary image]

As soon as I import it into Mathematica however and call ByteCount[image] the size increases to 1MB (8bit?). How can I prevent this? I do not have enough RAM to import that many 1MB images.

Best,
Max

Comment: your 132k files are compressed. Since they are almost all black you might store the data as a `SparseArray`,but then you wont be able to view or process as an image.